# Make rspec test pass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have a test for which I need to write the code to make it pass. 
The test is this:

```
require 'lib/String.rb'
RSpec.describe String do
  context '.to_h' do
    let(:hash) { { 'hello' => 'tree' } }

    it 'it should return the string parsed as a hash' do
      expect(hash.to_s.gsub('=>', ':').to_h).to eq(hash)
    end

    it 'should raise parse error if there was a parsing error' do
      expect { hash.to_s.to_h }.to raise_error(String::ParseError)
      expect(String::Error).to be < StandardError
      expect(String::ParseError).to be < String::Error
    end
  end
end
```

The code I wrote so far is:

```
class String
    class ParseError < StandardError
        def initialize
            String.const_set("Error", self)
        end
    end

    def to_h
        if self.split(":").count>1
             eval(self.split(":")[0]+"=>"+self.split(":")[1])
        else
            raise ParseError
        end
    end
end
```

In the test I have "expect(String::Error).to be < StandardError". I don't understand what this statement means. What is the String::Error and what the the "<" operator in this case?

Comment: Welcome Daniel, I think its worth taking the time to read this before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you may save your self from frustrations trying to get your answer :)

Comment: Hello Daniel. Go ahead and follow @JPSilvashy suggestion. I don't understand what your problem is here.

Comment: Sorry, thank you guys. Will update the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> In the test I have `expect(String::Error).to be < StandardError`. I don't understand what this statement means.

It means that `String::Error` should inherit from `StandardError`. Similarly for `String::ParseError`.

> What is the `String::Error`

It's a class/constant.

> and what the the "<" operator in this case?

Operator "less than" has special behavior when used on classes. One class is considered "less than" another class if it is its descendant.

---

> Maybe it's too much to ask but it would really help me a lot if someone could write the code for this spec.

I'm not going to write all of the implementation, but here's how people normally define custom exception classes.

```
class String
  class Error < StandardError
  end

  class ParseError < Error # Error is resolved to String::Error here, which is defined above
  end
end
```

If your exception classes do not contain any custom methods, this is a better/shorter form of the above.

```
class String
  Error = Class.new(StandardError)
  ParseError = Class.new(Error)
end
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I have added the code I wrote so far in the question. It did not get saved when I first added the question.
In the spec there is already a String::ParseError . Why and where should the String::Error go? Is this part of ruby (because I didn't find any info on it) or should I define it?
Maybe it's too much to ask but it would really help me a lot if someone could write the code for this spec. I already spent many hours trying to figure it out.
Thanx

Comment: And also how can String:Error be descendant of String:ParseError and in the same time String:ParseError be descendant of String:Error?

Comment: @DanielBelaToma "And also how can String:Error be descendant of String:ParseError and in the same time String:ParseError be descendant of String:Error?" - no, you read that wrong. Hierarchy should be like this: `String::ParseError < String::Error < StandardError`

Comment: @DanielBelaToma: yes, you're supposed to define `String::Error` and `String::ParseError`. Your code did get posted/saved, but I removed it, since it had nothing to do with the questions.

Comment: "Operator "less than" has special behavior when used on classes." – Not really. It means "send the message `<` to the object on the left passing as an argument the object on the right", which is the same thing it means everywhere else. Even its semantics are the same it has in most other places: inheritance induces a partial order on classes (actually modules), and `Module#<` is simply the "less-than" operator for that partial order.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yeah, what I should have said: "less-than operator is _defined_ for classes". Because classes are not the first thing to come to mind when you think about things you can test for range inequality.

Comment: "operator is defined" as in "classes understand message <"